# In an LDAP search filter, is it possible to ask for the 1st, 2nd, nth, or last value of a multi-valued field?

Tags: java, ldap, ldif

Using a search filter, is it possible to retrieve the last value of a multi-valued field for an object e.g. the department field of the inetOrgPerson?

For instance, if my user cn=Alice has 2 values for department, can I somehow write a search filter that will return the last value only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDAPSearch filters are meant to find and filter LDAP entries.
In the LDAP request, the list of attributes to retrieve is a separate parameter from the filter.
An LDAP Extension (a Control) exists to specify to match and retrieve only matching values of a multi-valued attribute, specified in RFC 3876. This extension is not implemented in all LDAP directory services, nor in all LDAP clients.

Comment: So the short answer is no, right? Thanks for your detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

I found a draft for ordered entries and values:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-chu-ldap-xordered-00

If your LDAP server implements this schema extension you might succeed in searching for the nth value of a multi-valued attribute